# How can i format each string in the List?

Tags: c#

I have this function and I need it to format the strings in the list to be with http:// in the beginning:

```
        private List<string> offline(string targetDirectory)
        {

            List<string> directories = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
                {

                    directories.Add(dirs[i]);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }        
            return directories;    
        }
```

The function return a List of strings of directories in the hard disk.
    Like `c:\` and `c:\windows`

I want that the List in the end will be instead of `c:\\` and `c:\\windows` in `index[0]` and `index[1]` to be formatted to: `http://c:\` and `http://c:\windows` and `http://c:\temp` so each string the List will be with http:// in the beginning.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so each string the List will be with http:// in the beginning.

```
List<string> newList =  directories.Select(r=> "http://" + r).ToList();
```

Or

```
var list2 = directories.Select(r => string.Concat("http://", r)).ToList();
```

Comment: Very elegant use of linq.  However if the OP cannot figure out a simple "`http://" + my_old_text` concatenation, it may be too much to learn at once :-(

Answer (score 0):

Why not append while adding to list

```
directories.Add("http://" + dirs[i]);
```

Or

```
return directories.Select(rs=> "http://" + rs).ToList()
```

Or

```
directories.ForEach(rs=>rs= "http://" + rs);
return directories;
```